# How can I parent a plane to only the y-position of my camera?

Tags: camera

I have a sand dune scene with an image on a plane as the background. I'm ready to animate my camera with WASD controls, but in order to give the background the illusion that it is really far away, I need to pin it to the camera movement, kinda like what ducky3d did [here](https://youtu.be/hnLsktA4gmY?t=517) with the sun in his scene.

The difference is I want to be able to more freely move the camera, but when I do it like the example in the video, the illusion doesn't work because the plane then becomes parented normal to the camera's movement in all degrees of freedom.

I want to be able to parent the plane only to the y-movement of my camera, while being able to move the camera in any way I want. Here are some pictures of my camera view and a screenshot of my scene. [image][image]

Comment: You could try and use transformation constraints instead of parenting, or click the lock in the object info panel next to the transformation axis you want to stay still.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I ended up finding the exact answer by using the Copy Location constraint on the plane, selecting camera as the target, checking the box for Y and Offset! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Copy Location constraint on the plane, selecting camera as the target, checking the box for Y and Offset! Works perfectly!